# Custom authorization support in Apache webserver

Tags: apache2, authorization

I would like to know if I can hook in a custom authorization support in apache2 webserver. What I want to do is, based on the user logged in, I want to disable few HTML pages being served to UI. The logic to check permissions to static resources (html, css, js etc) for a given user is little complex so I cant use the already available authorization and access control support of apache2. I would want all the requests for static resources in my webapp should first go through my custom module (authorization) which then decides if this request can be served or redirected to some error page.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/25) talks about mod_python to implement custom Apache/Subversion Authentication/Authorization, but is quite generic.

Combined with the standard [<Location> Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location) this can be a solution for your problem.

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: @IanHunter The webarchive has a snapshot: http://web.archive.org/web/20110821065622/http://www.thoughtspark.org/node/25 What are the best practices to keep this kind of content accessible ? Copy/pasting that whole article from webarchive feels not really ethical.